# Zeppelin :org.apache.spark.SparkException: Yarn application has already ended

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, ambari, apache-zeppelin

I have an Ambari configuration.
I succeed to launch ./bin/spark-shell --master yarn-client
and do this command :

```
sc.parallelize(Seq("one", "two", "three"), 1)
```

Now when i try to do it on Apache zeppelin it throws me this error :

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Yarn application has already ended! It might have been killed or unable to launch application master.
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.waitForApplication(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.start(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:144)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:523)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.createSparkContext(SparkInterpreter.java:339)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.getSparkContext(SparkInterpreter.java:145)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.open(SparkInterpreter.java:465)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.ClassloaderInterpreter.open(ClassloaderInterpreter.java:74)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.open(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:68)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.interpret(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:92)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:300)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:169)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.FIFOScheduler$1.run(FIFOScheduler.java:134)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Note that to install zeppelin i exactly followed the tutorial on the website:
https://zeppelin.incubator.apache.org/docs/0.5.5-incubating/install/yarn_install.html

Do you have any idea what is going on with yarn.